# Avoid installing python/packages versions for each project. How to share a path containing packages and python versions between different projects?

Tags: python, vagrant

I'm using Windows OS and to isolate my projects and to keep track of Python versions and Library versions I sometimes use Anaconda and sometimes a Vagrant Machine (Usually using Ubuntu 18.04), depending on the project.

When I'm using **Vagrant** to emulate Ubuntu 18.04, **I always have to install the same packages over and over for each new project** within the virtual environment folder for that project and I wonder if there's a better solution not to do that and still keep track of versions. **Can you suggest me something to help me on that?** (If you can, it would be awesome if you could share a link to a tutorial to do that as well)

Is there a way for me to keep track of the python and libraries versions on a *.txt file like the `requirements.txt` file and through that tool make it search for that package version in a single path, **sharing that single folder containing python versions and library versions among every single project I have instead of having to re-install packages in that specific project folder?**

If there is, **can I still push to git a virtual environment containing those packages and the python version** I'm using without mixing it up with the other versions I have installed? **I don't want to store that virtual environment files in my computer, but I still want to make it available in my project when I push it to GitHub, for instance.**

Thank you very much

Comment: I’m pretty sure that Conda does not reinstall a package from scratch if it is already used by another environment.

Comment: Yes, but Vagrant does and I have some Web Application projects that run on Ubuntu 18.04, so I have to use Vagrant to emulate Ubuntu 18.04 and it will always store every single version of the libraries I'm using on the `venv`folder for that project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to create the list of installed Python packages. You can use

```
$ pip list --format=freeze > installation_list.txt
```

This will export the list of packages with versions and save them into text file. Instead of *freeze* you can also use *JSON* or *legacy* as valid list format.

You can use `$ pip install -r installation_list.txt` to install from the given dependencies.

For pushing these files to git without mixing with other version. I would advise to create a separate branch for these versions and push to that. It will make it easier to maintain different version without any conflicts.
Whenever you want you can change to that branch by

```
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

Create new origin for that remote if needs be.